# Greek Letters in Latex Table

Tags: tables

I have been using [online latex editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) for generating equations for my blog. I am kind of novice to Latex. Now I want to generate a table for the first time. But when I try to write a greek letter into a table cell I get invalid equation error.

A sample code is:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|} 
\hline
2 & \alpha & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

This `\alpha` generates the "invalid equation" error, I want a greek alpha letter there.

Sorry if it is too simple but after half an hour I am still stuck. Thanks in advance...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your answer was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or edit your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Table cells are not in math mode. You need to add a math environment around mathematical contents.
Try this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
$2$ & $\alpha$ & $4$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I've just tried this with your online editor, but it seems that the language it recognizes is restricted. (This would work with a standard latex compiler).

Comment: still doesn't work, I suppose it is something related with the site or something?

Comment: @Dogan_79: The site you linked to is an equation editor, so if you surround the table with `$\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}$, this solution generats the desired table.

Comment: @PeterGrill: If it's an equation, `array` would be better than `tabular`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Yep that is a better answer -- you should post it.  I was just focused on figuring out why the `tabular` was not working.  Not sure why, but I do not have a notification of this message...

Comment: @Peter: Indeed, it's a better answer. You didn't have a notification because it was posted before the migration.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: I should still have received notification either here, or at the other site.

Comment: You can make a bug report on MSO, I'll be happy to upvote it.